# Good pain from a healing wound

Tags: pain, nerves, wound

Why does it feel so good (not dull pain), to encircle or press on a healing wound with a finger at a proximity that is very close to the border of the wound?

For example, a healing bruise feels so good when pressed against and a flesh wound when encircled with a finger.

Comment: The same way as a healing wound or bruise is sensitive to touch it is also sensitive to the pressure of the nearby tissues, blood and inflammatory material. When you press near the wound in a certain way, the pressure within the wound changes and you can feel this as pain relief.

Comment: That's a start but not the complete medically and psychologically inclined answer I was looking for.

Comment: There are certain stimuli that can temporarily cancel each other. Scratching cancels itching. Pressing, rubbing or cooling a painful area can decrease pain, etc.